# how to create a 2D array using vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

previously i thought that this code works for creating  a 2D array

```
    vector<vector<int>> array;
int m=3,n=3;
array.resize(m);
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    array[i].resize(n);
}
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;i<n;j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = i+j;
    }
}
```

but it turns out that this doesn't work , because when i try to get the value of, say array[0][1], this gives 0, but it should give 1.

So, i say that there is only one reason for that and that is its not a 2D array.

If the code is right and i am making a mistake please tell me the mistake or else please suggest me a way to make a 2D array using vectors.

Thanks you

Comment: The inner for loop should be `for(int j=0;j<n;j++)`.

Comment: You should still avoid `vector<vector>`. Use a simple `vector` instead and wrap it in something that does index calculation.

Comment: i realize my mistake, but now it is giving a runtime error. my program crashed.

Comment: `std::vector<int> array(m*n);`. Write a little class that implements array access with `int& operator(int row, int col)`.

Comment: If your program crashes just use a debugger. It should stop right at the point that causes the crash and you can inspect why it crashed there and how it got to that point.

Comment: @manni66 can you please elaborate your point. What i have to do exactly.

Comment: modify you inner for loop as that might be the reason of crashing

Comment: @AlbinPaul "Just try stuff and hope it works", is not such a good approach to solving a crash, especially with fun stuff like UB lurking in the background.

Comment: what exactly i have to do to make it work? its not a 2D array (although i thought it was )

Comment: i was not intending on trying stuff , this program will give segmentation fault in the inner loop .modify it as  said in the top comment

Comment: @AlbinPaul i did modify it, after that my program crashed.

Comment: @adityarawat There's no lethally wrong code in your example, crash must be coming from somewhere else. As already suggested, just use a debugger, the problem should become quickly apparent :-).

Comment: ok, i dont know how the code given by @AlbinPaul got deleted. but it worked. The code was similar to mine, so it maybe the problem with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
vector< vector<int> > matrix(m,vector<int>(n));

for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;i<n;j++)
        matrix[i][j] = i+j;
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, this is a much cleaner way of giving a `std::vector` within a `std::vector` an initial size than shown in the op's code, but how does it solve the op's problem?

Comment: my problem isn't my program got crashed, it was that my code didn't work as it should. I will now use a debugger to locate the problem in previous code. Thanks to all of you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
vector < vector<int> > array;
int m=3,n=3;
array.resize(m);
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    array[i].resize(n);
}
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = i+j;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cout<<array[i][j] ;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

    return 0;
}
```